# How can i resolve this emulator related error

Tags: android

Error message:

```
[2012-08-14 17:32:18 - thermometer] Failed to install thermometer.apk on device 'emulator-5556': Connection refused: connect
[2012-08-14 17:32:18 - thermometer] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[2012-08-14 17:32:18 - thermometer] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Restart your emulator. And, try to install it again.

Comment: adb kill-server, adb kill-server, adb start-server

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

Then its not working Check your **Antivirus** program control dialogs e.g Norton Antivirus and ZoneAlarm or ESET.